# MPMoviePlayerController overlay

Tags: iphone, video, overlay, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm loading video from external URL in my iphone app. This loading takes few minutes as the control downloads the video. While the video is being downloaded, I would like to display a small snapshot of the video (separate png file) on top of the media player control. This would be similar to the youtube app which displays a snapshot while video is downloading and the snapshot goes off when playback starts.

Any hints as how this can be achieved?

regards,
D2

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new UIImageView with your png, and `[moveiPLayerController.view addSubview:myPNGImgView];` to display it.  When the movie is loaded, then do a `-removeSubview`.